# Is there a way to run some code as an object is being destroyed?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, garbage-collection

In C# I know that my objects are garbage collected when they go out of scope and there are no more pointers/references to it. Is there a way to run some custom code when this garbage collection occurs?

Comment: Yes, but you probably shouldn't.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just a side note: the objects generally aren't collected right away.

Comment: @Cameron In my case that is ok :)

Comment: Really keen to know what your use case is. From everything I know there is nothing useful you can do there.

Comment: @HemalPandya: In classes which implement `IDisposable`, it's often useful to write a finalizer which asserts (and call `SuppressFinalize` from `Dispose`).  If the assertion fires, it means resources were leaked (temporarily).

Comment: @Ben that seems a nice one..I have often wondered if there was a way to force the use of an IDisposable only within a using statement.

Comment: @HemalPandya: using statements unfortunately aren't good enough.  What about disposable objects that need to live longer than a single function call?  Have a look at C++/CLI "stack semantics", which make sure the object is correctly disposed, and work for locals and also for class members (fields).

Comment: @Ben coming from a C++ background (loong back) it was a shock to find that destructor calls have to be explicit. I was just thinking of a special class of types that can only live within a block.

Comment: @HemalPandya My use-case is actually quite specific. I am working on a pet project called [U413](http://u413.googlecode.com). It's a command-prompt style message board just for fun. I use the repository pattern with Entity Framework and my repository objects go in and out of scope with each command sent. I want to call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` when the repository is being garbage collected. Even if it's not *exactly* when my object goes out of scope it is okay.

Comment: @AlexFord: You'd better be using `Dispose` then.  What happens if your finalizer runs after `DbContext` has been finalized?  Finalizers might not run until the end of the program if the program doesn't run out of memory, and then they run in no particular order.

Comment: "I want to call DbContext.SaveChanges() when the repository is being garbage collected." - That's a horrible idea.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for being constructive.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am using `IDisposable` with using statements. Will this suffice? I am under the impression `Dispose` is called when the using block finishes, which would in turn finalize the repository? Or would it simply be better to forget finalize and call my DbContext.SaveChanges() in dispose?

Comment: Alex Ford: This won't work like you expect it to. See the top comment from SLaks, much better advice than Ben Voigts (technically correct) answer.

Comment: Ben answered the exact question I asked so his answer is fine to be accepted. I am simply following a short tangent.

Comment: @AlexFord: Yes, definitely you should put your cleanup logic in `Dispose`.  And call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);`.  Then write a finalizer that does nothing except complain loudly, that someone forgot to call `Dispose`.

Comment: @AlexFord not sure if you realize but I did you a BIG favor by asking for your use-case :) Either Ben or you should edit the edit the accepted answer to warn on the pitfalls of using finalizer, specifically of assuming that any other references in it still valid.

Comment: @HemalPandya And you're humble too :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's called a *finalizer*. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxad3cah.aspx

Much of the C# documentation confusingly uses the term "destructor".  Although the C++ naming for a destructor is used in C# for a finalizer, the semantics are totally different.  If you consistently use the word *finalizer*, there won't be any confusion.

Comment: Bingo. I figured it would be something simple I was just unaware of. Thanks Ben.

Comment: In C# it _officially_ is the destructor. In the CLR it's the Finalize method. Confusing but dtor is the correct name here.

Comment: And let's not forget to warn about the undeterministic behavior of the finalizer. You never know when exactly it is going to be called. It could take a long.. long time before the GC calls it.

Comment: @Steven: That can be really bad.  So can the fact that objects finalized in the same GC cycle, are processed without regard to references between them.  A finalizer should not assume that any other objects still exist.

Comment: @Ben: The finalizer runs in managed code, and because a finalize method can access all referenced objects, the GC must keep them alive (that's one reason that undisposed finalizable objects can cause memory problems). In fact it is safe to call referenced objects, although you must keep in mind that those objects could be finalized as well. Although safe, using other objects from within the finalizer is a questionable approach that should be reviewed clearly.

Comment: @Steven: Like you said, those objects might have already been finalized, so aren't at all useful.

Comment: @Ben: True, but that doesn't mean that you can't access any object, since most objects aren't finalizable :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can define a finalizer for your class:

```
class Lava
{
    ~Lava()    // Finalizer -- runs when object is collected
    {
        // TODO: Clean up molten rock
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Finalizer/Destructor` (`~`) method.

[MSDN - Object.Finalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of a destructor in C# - the best you can do is add a [finalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (which has destructor syntax) which is then scheduled for execution on a dedicated finalizer thread when the GC would have normally collected your object - this does cause additional overhead though and keeps your object instance alive longer than it should have been. Consider the use case carefully.